# Question on Math.floor on negative number

Tags: elementary-number-theory

why do these return different results?

Math.floor(-1735)=-1735

Math.floor(-17.35*100)=-1736

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Javascript language

Comment: This question may be better suited for http://stackoverflow.com/, the good folks over there may have a better understanding of how this works. My guess is it has something to do with processing -17.35 as a float. What about -17.35*1000 and -17350?

Comment: I could be an issue with floating point numbers.  For a video explanation, see [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PZRI1IfStY0) that I like.

Comment: It is not an JavaScript issue, just an example that exposes the limits of the standard floating point routines.

Answer (score 4):

$-17.35$ is a [floating point number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) which cannot be represented exactly.  Your experiment indicates that the actual representation is slightly less than $-17.35$, so on multiplying by $100$ you get a number slightly less than $-1735$, so the floor is $-1736$

Answer (score 2):

If you output the value of $-17.35\cdot100$ you will see that it gives the seemingly wrong result:

$$-17.35\cdot100=-1735.0000000000002$$

(I tested this in Firefox, but other browsers should give the same result)

This is due to a rounding error. $-17.35$ can not be expressed exactly in a binary floating point number, since its denominator (when the number is expressed as a reduced fraction) is not a power of two.

Comment: Ok thank you guys. But how come -35.35 * 100 = -3535 ?

Comment: @user250443 Because the computer gets "lucky" with the way it rounds, in that case

Answer (score 1):

This is a rounding issue.  It may seem counterintuitive that we should have rounding issues when the numbers are so "nice".  However, the numbers are *not* nice in binary, which is how they are stored.

If we were to represent 17.35 as an exact value in binary, we would end up with
$$
10001.010110011... = 10001.010\overline{1100}
$$
Where the bar denotes a repeating decimal.  The computer stores this in a sort of "scientific notation".  In particular, the number is stored as
$$
\overbrace{1.0001010110011\dots 0\color{red}{10}}^{\text{53 digits}} \times 10^{100}
$$
where the red digits at the end correspond to the tail $...001(100)$ being rounded *up* to $...010$.

The net result of this rounding up is that when the computer attempts to calculate $100 \times 17.35$, it uses the exact value $100$ and a value *slightly higher* than $17.35$, so that the resulting product is *slightly higher that 1735*.  So, $-100 \times 17.35$ comes out to *slightly less than* $-1735$, so that the floor function rounds it down to $-1736$.

Answer (score 0):

This should explain the different behaviour for $-17.35$ and $-35.35$:
\begin{align}
-17.35 
&= (11000001100010101100110011001101)_{\tiny\mbox{IEEE 754}} \\
& = -17.350000381469727 \\
& < -17.35
\end{align}

and

\begin{align}
-35.35 
&= (11000010000011010110011001100110)_{\tiny\mbox{IEEE 754}} \\
&= -35.349998474121094 \\
&> -35.35
\end{align}

Note: These are 32-bit representations, for 64-bit I expect the same behaviour.